# Import into sql database from excel where data is horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ms-office

I am working on this database and I have to import this data from an excel sheet. But the problem is the data is Horizontal some what like this!

```
ID        Note1       Note2       Note3
2001      ABC         DEF         GHI
2002      XYZ         NULL        NULL
2003      MNO         PQR         NULL
```

And I want to add it into my table as

```
ID        Notes
2001      ABC
2001      DEF
2001      GHI
2002      XYZ
2003      MNO
2003      PQR
```

Is there any way I can insert this horizontal data from Excel into my table in SQL vertically?

Comment: How about writing formulae or vba to pivot your data for you?  Then import that?

Comment: I just tried importing the excel using the wizard in the SQL Management Studio. And i am finding it really tricky sort that data! :(

Comment: You need to be **specific** as to what the *actual* issue you are having is. As far as we know, @Andrew's answer should be sufficient.

Comment: Could you please say that then? @MitchWheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you receive the data in sql you can use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), clear examples [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/pivotunpivot/).

Comment: Thanks @Audor, That's something to look for! I will try it and let you know

Comment: Worked perfectly fine! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy. Arrange into two columns and use import feature...

Comment: Arrange into two columns? I didn't get you @Andrew

Comment: It would involve writing a macro.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new at this excel thing! Please elaborate! Thanks for your help!